# How to upload files with apollo-angular-graphql?

Tags: apollo-client, apollo-server

I am looking for a package which I can use for uploading files via graphql mutation using apollo-angular package. 
Also, can anyone help me understand which format will the file be uploaded and fetched to and from the server?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your server schema you need to define the file argument as type Upload. This is a built in type provided by Apollo. However if you do get errors about type Upload just add it as a [custom Scalar type](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/).

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const TypeDef = gql `

  scalar Upload

  type Mutation {
    upload(file: Upload!)
  }
`
```

In your revolvers you can access the file in your args, One thing to note is that the file will be a promise;

```
const resolver = {
        Mutation: {
            async upload(obj, args, context, info) {
                const file = await args.file;
                // ... DO STUFF
            },
        }
}
```

The package you are looking for for uploading files is the `apollo-angular-link-http` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-angular-link-http#file-upload). Within the query context you need to set useMultipart to true.

So a file upload request should look something like this.

```
// The Mutation Query Using Type of 'Upload' to represent the file 

const uploadFileMutation = gql`
  mutation UploadMutation($file: Upload!) {
    upload(file: $file) {
      YOUR RESPONSE
    }
  }
}

// The Apollo Client request 
// Context of 'useMultipart' needs to be set to true to enable file upload

this.Apollo.mutate<any>({
      mutation: uploadFileMutation,
      variables: {
         file: this.file
      },
      context: {
         useMultipart: true
      }
  }).subscribe(({ data }) => {
     this.response = data.upload
  });
```